# Mongoose - How to read and compare mongoose createdAt timestamp

Tags: javascript, mongoose

Mongoose timestamp option restore createdAt information like `2017-12-10T04:22:43.660Z` which I can't read into `Date`. What should I do to this information so that I can compare two timestamps to determine which one is created ealier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using Date.Parse("put the timestamp here") it should work. If not, try to define the time format and then parse it out. That will work.

Example of usage:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse

Answer (score 0):

I used `new Date(a) > new Date(b)`, where `a` and `b` are mongoose's `createdAt` strings.